# Error with runtime

Tags: jsp, shell, web-applications, button, command

I am new to jsp and runtime. I need to be able to run a script with a button on a web application page. The location of the script is in /home/user/ejbca_4/bin and to run it,

```
cd ejbca_4/bin
./ejbca.sh batch
```

Someone recommended to put these commands in a .sh file in /home/user/bin . I created /home/user/bin/test.sh with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ejbca_4/bin
./ejbca.sh batch
```

I added this to the jsp page

```
<input type="submit" name="Generate test" value='<c:out value="Generate Test"/>' tabindex="<%=tabindex++%>"
            onClick='generate()'>

function generate() {
  Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh",null,null);
}
```

but somehow this gave a NumberFormatException. I removed Process proc:

```
function generate() {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh",null,null);
}
```

and there was no NumberFormatException. However, the the script was not run. Can anyone explain how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand which part of your code is running on the server and which part is running on the client(browser). And you should never put code that should be run on the server  into the client side, because that won't work(obviously).

In your case, code that should be run on the server is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh", null, null);
```

It should be surrounded by `<% %>`

And the client side code is:

```
<input ... onclick='generate()'>
<script>
    function generate() {
        // tells the server to do 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the generate() function is in a script. So in the .jsp, it should have both?
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh", null, null); and the script?

Comment: This answer is technically correct.  If you've got server-side java code that needs to run that is called "scriptlet" and it goes inside of <% %> like infgeoax says.  It is scary, however, exec'ing out of Java to run a shell script.  In 10 years of java web development I have not seen anyone do this.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `function generate()` supposed to be?  I don't see that it's in any sort of tags, but it looks like JavaScript - when you're trying to invoke Java code.

Right now, your `onClick` will be handled client-side, and it needs a way to invoke your Runtime calls on the server-side.  Right now, the client doesn't have a path to make this happen.  You need to do some sort of callback (possibly using AJAX) that will result in the server executing your Runtime call.  If it remains in a JSP, you need it surrounded in `<% ... %>` to have it evaluated as Java code.

As you're new to JSPs, I'd highly recommend you go through Oracle's Web Tier tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html .